# Looking for a programming language to automate another Windows application

Tags: windows, automation

I have to deal with a proprietary Windows application on a regular basis. The tasks are always the same (open program, click spot 1, click spot 2, click 3...5) and then wait for a dialog box that says "Done." After which, the application must be closed again, the re-opened to start the task again. Wash, rinse, repeat.

I've tried using mouse clicker applications, but they can't they haven't worked too well. In particular, knowing when the application is done and not being smart enough if an errand click happens. Regardless, I'd like to create my own application to control this one. Is there a programming language that is particularly good at controlling other proprietary application?

Comment: Look for automation frameworks. How good they are depends on how much you are prepared to spend. AutoIt which is free will give you a start on the sort of considerations you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has the Robot class. See example usage below.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    private static final TimeUnit DAYS = TimeUnit.DAYS;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
             Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void doAutomation() {
             final Runnable auto = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                 try {
                        Robot robot = new Robot();
                        robot.delay(1000);// Delay 1 second. (1000ms)
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                        robot.mouseMove(0, 0);//Move mouse to 0,0 (Top left corner)(x,y)
                        robot.delay(15);//Delay 15 ms
                        robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
                    } catch (AWTException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
               };

             final ScheduledFuture<?> autoHandler =
               scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(auto, 0, 1, DAYS);//Perform task once per day.
    }

    public static final void main(String[] data) {

        Main m = new Main();
        m.doAutomation();

    }
}
```